# Laravel Send Mail fails

Tags: laravel-5, smtp, php-7

I installed laravel on my localhost server, i already configured my .env email setting.

This is my .env email setting

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This is the error i get.

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 95:
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Is there anyone know how to solve this problem? Appreciate that if you could guide me how to solve this.

Comment: Try this command php artisan config:cache

Comment: And restart the server

Comment: Hi Hackerman, I have followed your step, is also not working for me.

Comment: It works for me...can you create a repor on github and give me access...I can help you this weekend...if your answer is yes, you can contact me on my so profile

Comment: HI Hackerman, i think this is happen on my localhost, because i do it on my local.

Answer (score 1):

I have also found this very useful on the server level:

```
\vendor\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php
```

Edit 
line 259 ish. comment out the $options = array(); and add the below.

```
//$options = array();
    $options['ssl'] = array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true);
```

Comment: Hi Aan, thanks for the comment. 
Yes, this is the solution i used to solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be fine, I think that you just need to change some settings on you `gmail` account:

> First of all you need to make some changes in your gmail account settings.
>    You need to open your gmail account settings. The following page will get open.

[image]

> You need to click Signing in to Google. It will redirect you to the following page.

[image]

> There are 2 steps :

1. You need to keep the 2-step verification off, if you’re using it.
2. Then click on Connected apps & sites. It will redirect you to the following window.

[image]

> Here, you need to keep **Allow less secure apps : ON** .
>    And it’s done. That’s all you need to do.

Comment: HI, thank for your fast response, i have follow your step to do that. But it is not working for me. Below is my php and apache version.

Apache/2.4.23
PHP 7.0.12